# Why backbone add extra parameter to url path?

Tags: backbone.js, marionette

I am using backbone.marionette (1.0.0) and node.js (0.10.22).  Wondering why backbone add extra parameter when I try to save model data with node.js REST call.

**model.js**

```
 Backbone.Model.extend ({
     urlRoot: function (){
         return '/path/' + myApp.companyId;
    },
    defaults: {
       companyId: '',
       // other attributes
    },
    // doesn't use 'id' in model instead companyId
    idAttribute: 'companyId'
```

});

Before view is loaded, I would request model data with `myApp.request ('entities:myModel')` which issued `model.fetch ()` and node.js backend would fire `GET /path/1`  route. No issue.

However, when an update button is clicked on the view, this.model.save () would fired `PUT /path/1/1`.  It should be `PUT /path/1`, with only a single '1' in url path.

**view.js:**

```
clicked: function () {
   var formData = Backbone.syphon.serialize (this);
   this.model.set (formData);
   var promise =  this.model.save ();
   promise.done ().fail ()
}
```

How can I stop backbone.sync from appending extra parameter to url path?  Thanks for taking time out to read this, and I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're setting `urlRoot` incorrectly on the model. It should be

```
Backbone.Model.extend ({
  urlRoot: "path",
  // etc
});
```

Backbone willa dd the ids on it's own.

If you want to specify the ids in your function, use the `url` function.